# Copying final state of a functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send my state value from a component called 'Sb_Questions.tsx' to another component called 'Sb_Survey.tsx' using events. 'Sb_Survey.tsx' emits the `'send'` event and 'Sb_Questions.tsx' listens to it and them emits the answer object back (which is its state). The problem I have is that the when i send the Sb_Questions state it also sends previous states. For example if I input 'Hey' the state that logs out becomes 'H' 'He' Hey'. I want one output which is 'Hey'.

Sb_Questions.tsx

```
const Sb_Question : React.FC<Props> = ({ data, number, status}) => {

const [Answer, setAnswer] = useState({
    questionId:data.questionId,
    questionType:data.input,
    choiceId:null,
    ansText:null,
    isAnswered:false
});

function onChangeHandler (e?:any) :void {
    setAnswer({
        questionId:data.questionId,
        questionType:data.input,
        choiceId:null,
        ansText:e.target.value,
        isAnswered: Answer.ansText !== '' ? Answer.isAnswered = true : Answer.isAnswered = false,            
    })
}

Emitter.addListener('send', () => {
        Emitter.emit('answer_for_'+data.questionId, Answer);
        console.log(Answer) // This where it logs it out
    
})

return <Container className="question" id={data.questionId}>
    <Row className="question-text" ><Sb_Text font="reg12">{ number + 1 }. { data.question }</Sb_Text></Row>
    
    {   /* If its a text-field */
        data.input === 'text-field' &&
        <Row className="mb-4">
            <Container>
                <textarea 
                    className="text-area"
                    style={{resize:'none'}} 
                    rows={ status === 'filling' ? 5 : 2}
                    disabled={ status === 'preview'}
                    onChange={onChangeHandler}
                ></textarea>
            </Container>                
        </Row>
    }
</Container>
}

export default Sb_Question;
```

[image: Only wanted 'Hey' ,not the history]

How do I only get the final value?

Comment: provide a minimal code sandbox and I will try to help you. also, clarify your final goal

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have is that the when i send the Sb_Questions state it
> also sends previous states. For example if I input 'Hey' the state
> that logs out becomes 'h' 'he' hey'

It's not a previous state, input has value, you type something and add character to value, in `onChangeHandler` you use whole value every time. It's correct behavior. Your [input is uncontrolled.](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: I added `value` to my textarea and binded it with my state, but still the same thing.

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to achieve.

Comment: Normally you can'a pass values between sibling components on React. Can pass something as prop to children or return value with callback to parent.
If need to share value between components need to lift it up to common parent. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

`addListener` isn't a React way.